# Getting error Microsoft.AspNetCore.MVC 1.1.0 does not support framework .NETCoreApp, Version v1.1

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core-1.1

Trying to start an .Net CORE project with MVC.  Attempting to use the latest version of .Net CORE (v1.1) and I cannot get a version of MVC to work as a dependency. Below is my project.json file.

```
 {

  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "debugType": "portable",
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.1.0"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.1": {
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "type": "platform",
      "version": "1.1.0"
    }
  },
  "imports": [
    "dnxcore50"
      ]
    }
  },
  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "web.config"
    ]
  },
  "runtimeOptions": {
    "gcServer": true
  },
  "scripts": {
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder     %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  }
}
```

Gives this error:

> The dependency Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc 1.1.0 does not support framework .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just install runtime (not only SDK) from here: https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/core#/current/runtime.
Maybe you'll need execute "dotnet restore" command.
It helps to me.